# Angular2 animation is slow on long lists

Tags: css, angular, css-animations, angular2-animation

I'm using angular animation on a list component, a slide-in-out animation.
It works fine when the list is short, but when I have more then 50 items on the list, the animation is laggy.
What is the cause of that? how can it be solved?

Comment: Did you modified the height property of you list during your animations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the source to the performance issue. 
Added `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` to the root component, now everything is fast as it used to be, I hope that new issues won't be rising now :)

Comment: This gave me some good improvements to the app. Not an amazingly fast improvement, but it was faster. Thanks!